# Issues with PHP for loop entering names into database

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I am using the following code to enter submitted names into the database. The code, when working correctly, should capture the names and other information submitted in the form and create three unique entries in the database. This is not happening. Instead the code is capturing the last name in the three pack and entering its information into the database. You can view the form here [beta website](https://hlbeta.mhkinsmenticket.com/tickets). The payment processing script is disabled on the form. What do I need to change in the for loop code to fix this issue? Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you. **I have added all of the code that is used in the script below. Hopefully this will give you a better understanding of what is going on in the script.**

```
class DreamModelDream extends JModel {

function getDetails()
{
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    if($session->get('dreamticket'))
    {
        return $session->get('dreamticket');
    }
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->tickets = -1;
    $data->fiftytickets = '';
    $data->qty = 0;
    $data->fiftyqty = 0;
    $data->firstname = '';
    $data->firstname2 = '';
    $data->firstname3 = '';
    $data->lastname = '';
    $data->lastname2 = '';
    $data->lastname3 = '';
    $data->address = '';
    $data->address2 = '';
    $data->address3 = '';
    $data->city = '';
    $data->city2 = '';
    $data->city3 = '';
    $data->postal = '';
    $data->postal2 = '';
    $data->postal3 = '';
    $data->phone = '';
    $data->phone2 = '';
    $data->phone3 = '';
    $data->altphone = '';
    $data->altphone2 = '';
    $data->altphone3 = '';
    $data->email = '';
    $data->email2 = '';
    $data->email3 = '';
    $data->giftname = '';
    $data->giftaddress = '';
    $data->giftcity = '';
    $data->giftpostal = '';
    $data->sec_firstname = '';
    $data->sec_firstname2 = '';
    $data->sec_firstname3 = '';
    $data->sec_lastname = '';
    $data->sec_lastname2 = '';
    $data->sec_lastname3 = '';
    $data->agegroup = 0;
    $data->expm = 0;
    $data->expy = 0;
    $data->nameoncard = '';
    $data->cctype = '';
    $data->ccnum = '';
    $data->Media_Radio = false;
    $data->Media_TV = false;
    $data->Media_Newspaper = false;
    $data->Media_Mail = false;
    $data->Media_Web = false;
    $data->Media_Kinsmen_Member = false;
    $data->Media_Other = false;
    $data->Radio_CJCY = false;
    $data->Radio_MY96 = false;
    $data->Radio_ROCK = false;
    $data->Radio_CHAT = false;
    $data->Radio_POWER = false;
    $data->Radio_Other = false;
    $data->total = false;
    $data->billingphone = '';
    $data->agree = 0;
    $data->ord_type = 0;
    $data->creditcard = '';
    $data->user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    return $data;
}

function getConfirmDetails()
{
    $post = JRequest::get('post');
    $ticket = new stdClass();
    foreach($post as $key => $value)
    {
        $ticket->$key = $value;
    }
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $session->set('dreamticket', $ticket);
    if(!strlen($post['firstname'])){
        return "Your first name is missing<br>";
    }
    if(!strlen($post['lastname'])){
        return "Your last name is missing<br>";
    }
    if(!strlen($post['address'])){
        return  "Your address is missing<br>";
    }
    if(!strlen($post['city'])){
        return  "Your city is missing<br>";
    }
    if(!strlen($post['postal'])){
        return  "Your postal code is missing<br>";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^T\d\w\d\w\d$/i", $post['postal'])) {
        //return  "Your postal code is invalid for this province<br>";
    }   
    if(!strlen($post['phone'])){
        return  "Your phone number is missing<br>";
    }
    if(!strlen($post['email'])){
        return  "Your email is missing<br>";
    }
    if($post['tickets'] == '-1'){
    ////////// TICKET 2
        if(!strlen($post['firstname2'])){
            return  "Your first2 name is missing<br>";
        }
        if(!strlen($post['lastname2'])){
            return  "Your last2 name is missing<br>";
        }
        if(!strlen($post['address2'])){
            return  "Your address2 is missing<br>";
        }
        if(!strlen($post['city2'])){
            return  "Your city2 is missing<br>";
        }
        if(!strlen($post['postal2'])){
            return  "Your postal2 code is missing<br>";
        }
        if (!preg_match("/^T\d\w\d\w\d$/i", $post['postal2'])) {
            //return  "Your postal2 code is invalid for this province<br>";
        }   
        if(!strlen($post['phone2'])){
            return  "Your phone number2 is missing<br>";
        }
    /////////////Ticket 3
        if(!strlen($post['firstname3'])){
            return  "Your first name3 is missing<br>";
        }
        if(!strlen($post['lastname3'])){
            return  "Your last name3 is missing<br>";
        }
        if(!strlen($post['address3'])){
            return  "Your address3 is missing<br>";
        }
        if(!strlen($post['city3'])){
            return  "Your city3 is missing<br>";
        }
        if(!strlen($post['postal3'])){
            return  "Your postal code3 is missing<br>";
        }
        if (!preg_match("/^T\d\w\d\w\d$/i", $post['postal3'])) {
            //return  "Your postal code3 is invalid for this province<br>";
        }   
        if(!strlen($post['phone3'])){
            return  "Your phone number3 is missing<br>";
        }
    }   
    //////// END TICKET CHECK   

    if(!strlen($post['nameoncard'])){
        return  "Your Name on Credit Card is missing<br>";
    }
    if($post['cctype'] == "Please select one"){
        return  "Your Credit Card Type is missing<br>";
    }
    if(!strlen($post['ccnum'])){
        return  "Your Credit Card Number is missing<br>";
    }
    if(!strlen($post['billingphone'])){
        return  "Your billing phone number is missing<br>";
    }
    if(!strlen($post['agree'])){
        return  "Your must agree to the Lottery rules in order to proceed<br>";
    }
    return $ticket; 
}

function process()
{
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    jimport('joomla.database.table');
    $params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_dream');
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $data = $session->get('dreamticket');
    if(!is_object($data))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $dif = strtotime("-1 hour");
    $timestamp = date("F j, Y, g:i a",$dif);
    $ord_id = date('ymdHis') . rand(1000,9999);
    $ticket_total = (int) (($data->tickets == '-1') ? '250' : (int) $data->tickets * 100); 
    $fiftyticket_total = (int) (($data->fiftytickets == '0') ? '' : (int) $data->fiftytickets * 10);
    $ordertotal = $ticket_total + $fiftyticket_total;

    if(strlen($data->expm) == 1)
    {
        $data->expm = '0'.$data->expm;
    }
    if(strlen($data->expy) != 2)
    {
        $data->expy = substr($data->expy, 2, 2);
    }
    $data->total = $ordertotal;
    JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_BASE.DS.'administrator'.DS.'components'.DS.'com_dream'.DS.'tables');
    $table = JTable::getInstance('Tickets', 'Table');
    $table->auth = $auth;
    $table->billingphone = $data->billingphone;
    $table->Media_Radio = isset($data->Media_Radio) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Media_TV = isset($data->Media_TV) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Media_Newspaper = isset($data->Media_Newspaper) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Media_Mail = isset($data->Media_Mail) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Media_Web = isset($data->Media_Web) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Media_Kinsmen_Member = isset($data->Media_Kinsmen_Member) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Media_Other = isset($data->Media_Other) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Radio_CJCY = isset($data->Radio_CJCY) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Radio_MY96 = isset($data->Radio_MY96) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Radio_ROCK = isset($data->Radio_ROCK) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Radio_CHAT = isset($data->Radio_CHAT) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Radio_POWER = isset($data->Radio_POWER) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->Radio_Other = isset($data->Radio_Other) ? 1 : 0;
    $table->agegroup = $data->agegroup;
    $table->orderdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $table->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $table->ord_type = ($user->get('id') > 0) ? 'CallCentre' : 'online';
    $table->ord_id = $ord_id;
    if($data->tickets == '0') {
        $table->ticket_type = 'None';
    } elseif($data->tickets == '-1') {
        $table->ticket_type = '3Pack';
    } elseif($data->tickets == '1') {
        $table->ticket_type = '1ticket';
    } elseif($data->tickets == '5') {
        $table->ticket_type = '8tickets';
    }
    if($data->fiftytickets == '0') {
        $table->fiftyticket_type = 'None';
    } elseif($data->fiftytickets == '1') {
        $table->fiftyticket_type = '1ticket';
    } elseif($data->fiftytickets == '2') {
        $table->fiftyticket_type = '3tickets';
    }
    $table->province = 'AB';
    $table->creditcard = $data->cctype;
    if(isset($data->giftpurchase)) {
        $table->giftname = $data->giftname;
        $table->giftadress = $data->giftadress;
        $table->giftcity = $data->giftcity;
        $table->giftpostal = $data->giftpostal;
    }

    $data->ord_id = $ord_id;
    $tickets = 1;
    $table->qty = $data->tickets;
    if($data->tickets === '-1')
    {
        $tickets = 3;
        $table->qty = 3;
    } elseif($data->tickets === '1')
    {
        $tickets = 1;
        $table->qty = 1;
    } elseif($data->tickets === '5')
    {
        $tickets = 8;
        $table->qty = 8;
    }
    $threepack = '';
    $i = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $tickets; $i++)
    {
        $firstname = 'firstname'.$threepack;
        $lastname = 'lastname'.$threepack;
        $address = 'address'.$threepack;
        $city = 'city'.$threepack;
        $postal = 'postal'.$threepack;
        $phone = 'phone'.$threepack;
        $altphone = 'altphone'.$threepack;
        $sec_firstname = 'sec_firstname'.$threepack;
        $sec_lastname = 'sec_lastname'.$threepack;
        $email = 'email'.$threepack;

        $table->firstname = $data->$firstname;
        $table->lastname = $data->$lastname;
        $table->address = $data->$address;
        $table->city = $data->$city;
        $table->postal = $data->$postal;
        $table->phone = $data->$phone;
        $table->altphone = $data->$altphone;
        $table->sec_firstname = $data->$sec_firstname;
        $table->sec_lastname = $data->$sec_lastname;
        $table->email = $data->$email;
        $table->id = 0;

        if($data->tickets === '-1' || $data->tickets === '5')
        {
            if($threepack == 2)
            {
                $threepack = 3;
            } else {
                $threepack = 2;
            }
        }
    }
    $fiftytickets = 1;
    $table->fiftyqty = $data->fiftytickets;
    if($data->fiftytickets === '1')
    {
        $fiftytickets = 1;
        $table->fiftyqty = 1;

    } elseif($data->fiftytickets === '2')
    {
        $fiftytickets = 3;
        $table->fiftyqty = 3;

    }
    $table->order_total = $data->total;
    $table->store();

    //sending confirmation mail
    $mailcontent = '';
```

Comment: where are you incrementing `$threepack` variable?

Comment: ^ you are using for `$i` and incrementing `$i` but not making use of `$i` in your script.

Comment: Can you show how you handle the $_POST?

Comment: You need to expand your question. Where is the table object and data object initialized? And where is the $tickets variable initialized? and should that also be $data->tickets?  And your operators are incorrect if($data->tickets === should be if($data->tickets ==  And integers don't need to be in quotes, so '-1' would be -1 and '5' would be 5.  Please expand your question.

Comment: @StephanusYanaputra, I have added more code to the example including the $_POST and adjusting the for loop a bit. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < $data->tickets; $i++)
```

Comment: what about incrementing `$threepack`, to add multiple tickets?

Comment: You have a syntax error, $data->$tickets should be $data->tickets.. And we have no way knowing if $tickets in the for loop was even supposed to be part of that object.  His question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issues with the for loop. The fiftytickets code needed to be moved above the for loop and the $table->store() function needed to be moved into the for loop and placed after the $table->id line. Now when a ticket or tickets are purchased, three entries with the same name or unique names are inserted into the database.